# Uniao apenas se a query acima devolver registos

Tags: mysql, sql

Boas pessoal,

Gostaria de saber qual a abordagem que adotariam para fazer uma união apenas se a query acima, da união, devolver valores.
Considerem que as tabelas sã compatíveis
EX:

```
SELECT * FROM Tabela1
UNION
SELECT * FROM Tabela2 
/*Esta query so deve ser executada apenas se a query acima, select * from Tabela1, tiver devolvido algum valor*/
```

Cumprimentos,
Leandro

Comment: Até onde sei você não consegue.

Comment: @Ricardo Diretamente acho que realmente não existe nada assim. Mas existirá alguma forma de "provocar" esse comportamento?

Comment: Deu certo a query abaixo?

Comment: @DotNet Me desculpe mas ainda nao consegui testar. Estou sem acesso a base de dados. No entanto já vi a proposta e percebi o teu pensamento. No entanto tenho uma duvida. O tipo de dados table existe em mysql?

Comment: Se você se refere a criação "declare @Tabela2 table", não exatamente dessa forma.

Comment: O tipo table existem em qualquer banco de dados, agora a criação tabela temporária varia em alguns bancos, a forma que utilizei é para SQLSERVER, mas o select em si funciona no mysql sem problema.

Answer (score 0):

Só se você usa a tabela acima para filtra a segunda

```
declare @Tabela1 table
(
    id int
)

declare @Tabela2 table
(
    id int
)

--insert into @Tabela1 values (1),(2),(3),(4)
insert into @Tabela2 values (1),(2),(3),(5)


SELECT * FROM @Tabela1
UNION
SELECT * FROM @Tabela2 
where exists (SELECT top 1 id FROM @Tabela1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Fiz um teste com a instrução abaixo e funcionou (acho que está fácil de entender):

```
select * from bairro where id = 1
   union
   select * from bairro where id > 15 and
     EXISTS (select FIRST 1 * from bairro where id = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá, peço que experimento o seguinte código:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT * FROM Tabela1
  UNION
  SELECT * FROM Tabela2
) a
WHERE EXISTS(
  SELECT 1 FROM Tabela1
)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT
*
FROM(
    SELECT * FROM Tabela1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * from Tabela2) as aux
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Tabela1) > 0
```